# Replacement of the patterns in the replacement

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I want to make such changes:
$(A\, p + B\, q)[i] \to A\, p[i]+B\, q[i]$

But the replacement below can not do this

```
(A p + B q)[i] /. {(x_[y_]) -> ((x) /.{p -> p[y],q->q[y]})}
```

Why is this not working and how to realize this kind of changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transformation rule won't work because the RHS of a rule will evaluate immediately. Thus,

```
{(x_[y_]) -> ((x) /.{p -> p[y],q->q[y]})}
```

is equivalent to `{x_[y_] -> x}`.

As to how to do what you want, you can use [RuleDelayed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) if you want to keep the same pattern.

```
(A p + B q)[i] /. {(x_[y_]) :> ((x) /.{p -> p[y],q->q[y]})}
(* A p[i] + B q[i] *)
```

There's lots of other ways to do this also. Here's one of them using [Through](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html?q=Through), which distributes operators.

```
Through[(A p + B q)[i]] /. (x_*y_)[z_] -> x*y[z]
(* A p[i] + B q[i] *)
```